# PHP HTML Entity Decode Issues

Tags: php, html, entity, decode

I'm on PHP 5.5.8 and saw that I was getting weird data, turns out when I decode html entities I'm getting some type of corrupted characters or something.

`echo html_entity_decode('&#233;');`

Displays ├® in my terminal and Ã© in a browser, when it should be é. I've used `html_entity_decode('&#233;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` and defined my default charset to be UTF-8 as well. The thing is I've tried it on another server and it worked fine. But on my local environment it's failing so .. probably something to do with some settings but I don't know where to look. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to decode them before putting them in the browser? A browser will decode the entities automatically.

Comment: No, that was just for testing purposes. It is being decoded to insert into my database and then used at a later time (not in a website). This is why I am not simply leaving the entities alone, they won't be used in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a mismatch of encodings, check in your php.ini, if your default_charset there is not utf-8, that will mess things up.

You can also set it at run time with ini_set.

ini_set ( 'default_charset', 'utf-8' );

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any mismatch?. If your default_charset is utf-8, your database connection is utf-8, your http headers are utf-8, the php file itself is utf-8 and the form data is utf-8, there should be no inconsistencies.

Comment: Well even simply echoing it so disregarding the database/form data/http headers..that leaves the file and default charset to be utf-8. I have used php_ini to set the default charset and declared it in my php.ini file as well. The file is most definitely utf-8. I guess that means my terminal isn't outputting utf-8?

Comment: what system do you have? If is linux, remember to configure your locale on the locale.gen file and execute locale-gen after that. Or whichever configuration your system needs. If it's windows, I'm sure there are many websites that explain how to check if the console is in utf-8 or how to change it if needed.